# Should I remove the generated platform/ folder from my tracked code?

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

For some reason I noticed that someone on my team as committed and pushed the platform directory generated code for the ionic framework / cordova.  Since it is generated based on the machine, I think that I should remove it from my source tree and just make sure the packages.json file is updated with whatever platforms/plugins were needed to generate the correct code.

I figure that i should then add platforms/ to my .gitignore file so they dont do it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO This is the correct way to publish ionic applications to github. However, there is a catch. When you are building the application for native devices, you will likely run into instances when you need to change platform-specific configuration files in the `/platforms` folder. If you are working with a team and need each member to be able to build the app for deployment, then you will need to ensure their configurations are synced with yours. Usually I only use one machine to do builds for my ionic apps, so this isn't a problem.

Here's a copy of my usual ionic .gitignore:

```
www/lib
node_modules/
platforms/
plugins/
node_modules
.idea
.temp
.sass-cache
*.swp
*.swo
*.log
*.DS_Store
```

Comment: I have been working with the browser for the time being just because I need a new android device for 1 and for 2, i want a new mac to do dev with.... So when I actually expand this from `ionic serve` to `ionic build` with a variety of platforms it may need some tweaking